# "Share to facebook" button issue in displaying thumbnails

Tags: facebook, button, share, thumbnails

I have added a "share to Facebook" button in all my website's articles.

Clicking this button would normally open a new window showing the Facebook post's preview: the post's title, the post's description, and the ability to select one of the page's images, as a thumbnail to my Facebook post.

Without no reason, the past few days, this functionality has problems. There are no thumbnails to select and eventually the post in Facebook looks like

"WEBSITE URL" [post title]
website url... [post description]

Can you please help me find what's the reason for this, because I couldn't manage to solve it myself.

Comment: -Have you checked that the thumbnails are there still?
-What size are the thumbnails?
-Can I see your HTML for linking the thumbnail in the header, and your html for sharing?

Comment: Can you post your code? which version of share button are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running your URL thru Facebook's linter tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and fix any issues it has with your og: tag setup.  Once that is fixed, then you can troubleshoot why the plugin is not picking up the information correctly.